# Как вывести значение из функции $.get до отправки формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, асинхронность

Делаю функцию на проверку корректности данных при отправлении формы. Есть переменная error с номерами ошибок. Если error == 0, то отправляем форму, если нет, то выводим соответствующую ошибку и return false.
Внутри функции есть $.get-функция, которая делает одну из проверок (и в случае, если данные некорректные, то меняет значение error).
Проблема: так как функция асинхронная, то присвоение переменной происходит уже после того, как отправляется форма (то есть проверка не срабатывает).
Вопрос: как передать значение error ДО того, как внутри функция пойдёт проверка на  error == 0. Или же как приостановить отправку формы до того, как обработается $.get-функция?

```
$("#button").submit(function () {// обрабатываем отправку формы
    var error = 0; // индекс ошибки
...
//первая проверка (классическая, с ней всё хорошо)
if (a > b) {
        error = 1;
    }

...
 $.getJSON('json.json', function (data) {
...
              if  (...){
                  setResult("2"); // присваиваем error значение 2
              }

...
    });

//присваиваем значение внутри get-функции
function setResult(result) {
        error = result;
} 
...
дальше проверки error, и return true, если error == 0 или вывод ошибок + return false.
```

P.S. Тут есть замечательный ответ: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) -- но что-то не особо помогло, так как мне не просто передать значение нужно, а передать его ДО проверки на error == 0 и отправки формы.

Comment: я не понял что именно надо приостановить до чего?

Comment: Пока закрыл как дубликат, отредактируй свой вопрос добавив больше подробностей и что именно пробовал. Попробуй сделать [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy мне нужно не присвоить значение (это-то получилось --функция setResult как раз взята из того вопроса (Способ 0+)), а чтобы это значение присвоилось ДО того, как отправится форма (или же как-то приостановить отправку формы до того, как вернётся присвоенное значение). Мне кажется, это немного другой вопрос.
Не знаю, как сделать воспроизводимый пример с json-файлом, который на компе лежит...

Comment: На самом деле ты не совсем верно понял, что _должна_ делать та функция. В том вопросе как раз упор на то и делается, что все действия которые должны быть после запрос должны выполняться в коллбэке. А здесь ты в коллбэке присваиваешь только значение переменной, причем по приведенному коду нельзя сказать _той ли_ переменной ты присваиваешь или другой. Плюс неизвестно как именно происходит submit. Поэтому сделай пример чуть ближе к твоему коду, убрав то, что не относится к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Я чуть подправил, если идея тольrо в том, чтобы показать юзеру, отправлена ли форма, то function (data) { - и есть колбек, в нём мы можем проверить данные json на ошибку, если не ошибка, показать клиенту, что все ок, высветить модальное окно или алерт с надписью "Форма успешно отправлена", если хотя бы одна из проверок по цепочке внесла ошибку, то сделать что-нибудь другое:

```
$("#button").click(function (event) {
    var error = false
    event.preventDefault();
    if (a > b) error = true;
    .....
    $.getJSON('json.json', function (data) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
          if (...) {
             error = true  
          }
        });
        if (!error) {
            //Все ок!
            .....//Тут что-нибудь делаем
            alert('Form was send!');
        } else {
               //Где-то в цепочке проверок вылезла ошибка
                alert('Error!');
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую поработать с кликом, а не с submit. Только не совсем понял, как вынести проверки из GET? Я GET и вызываю только для проверки (если значение уже есть в json-файле, то меняю значение ошибки). Но в этому случае значение ошибки в этом случае меняется уже после отправки формы.

Comment: Я сейчас понял, у вас ошибка в логике. Вы сначала получаете данные с get, только потом можете их проверить.  Что вам надо сделать с результатом синхронно?

Comment: Да, я так и хотел. Получить данные с get, проверить, есть ли уже это значение в json-файле, и если есть, то запретить отправку формы. Асинхронность мне в этой проверке мешает.
Порядок такой:
1)Получить данные с get
2) обработать их
3) изменить значение error, если нужно
4)Проверить значение error и (если error != 0) запретить отправку формы.

А у меня 3 пункт идёт после 4-го.